# ALAsset thumbnail without inward black translucent border

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, alasset

I have find that for most photos in the gallery, `[ALAsset thumbnail]` will return the thumbnail with an inward black translucent border.

My question is, how can I obtain the thumbnail without this border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of options. If you just need to display it on screen you could simply fake it so that 1 pixel of the thumbnail isn't visible. You can put a UIImageView inside a UIView that clips to bounds.

```
UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
view.clipsToBounds = YES;
UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-1, -1, 202, 202)];
imgView.image = [asset thumbnail];
[view addSubview:imgView];
```

Or better yet, make a UIView subclass and override drawRect.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage* thumb = [asset thumbnail];
    [thumb drawInRect:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x-1, rect.origin.y-1, rect.size.width+2, rect.size.height+2)];
}
```

Or you can use the aspectRatioThumbnail instead and make it squared yourself.

```
UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
imgView.image = [asset aspectRatioThumbnail];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Or if you actually need to crop the UIImage itself for some reason you can do this.

```
UIImage* thumb = [asset thumbnail];
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(1, 1, thumb.size.width-2, thumb.size.height-2);
cropRect = CGRectMake(cropRect.origin.x*thumb.scale, cropRect.origin.y*thumb.scale, cropRect.size.height*cropRect.scale);       

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([thumb CGImage], cropRect);
UIImage* result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:thumb.scale orientation:thumb.imageOrientation]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no methods to get thumbnail without 1 pixel black border.

You can use also

```
 [asset aspectRatioThumbnail]; // but it is not rounded.
```

So i think you should resize the image yourself using:

```
asset.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage or
asset.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage
```

Comment: fullScreenImage or fullResolutionImage slows the code, right?

Comment: sure, if the image is big than slows strongly, so better is to use thumbnails